# Beginner working with generative models

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, generative-models

I'm getting a set of 20-dimensional feature vectors. I'm getting a 100 vectors per second. These feature vectors are occuring in a sequence, where one feature vector depends on the one that came before it.

Feature vector: $(x_{1}, x_{2}, ... , x_{20})$, where $x_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$

For every such vector, I have a 2-dimensional  "label" vector $(y_{1},y_{2})$, where $1 \leq y_{i} \leq 0$.

For a concrete example, let's assume that we're working with self-driving cars and each dimension of the feature vector represents some attribute of the car's control.

Feature 1 could be steering angle, feature 2 could be the car's speed, etc. while the "labels" could refer to the $(\Delta x, \Delta y)$ increment by which the car has traveled since the last vector was measured.

I probably would have around 100,000 of these vectors.

My goal was to design a neural network which, once trained on the data-set, would take in a 2-dimensional vector $(y_{1},y_{2})$ and generate an appropriate 20-dimensional feature vector of observations.

Being a newbie, I had the vague idea of using a recurrent neural network to create a generative model from having learned the vectors--adapting the approach of [Alex Graves' paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0850).The thought of using variational autoencoders or generative adversarial networks did occur to me, but I felt that it may be overkill at this point.

However, is this the best approach to solve this problem?
Could someone recommend a better approach, if it isn't?

Comment: Do you know if the sequence is "stationary" or not? That is, how much "memory" is needed? (In other words, if $\vec{y}_t|\vec{x}_{1:t} \approx \vec{y}_t|\vec{x}_{t-T:t}$, where perhaps even $T\approx 0$, the recurrent aspect would itself be overkill.)

Comment: The sequence isn't stationary, it's changing over time. I just included a concrete example relating to self-driving cars in the text of the question for clarity.

Comment: Why don't you train your neural network on $(y_1, y_2)$ as your features and $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_{20}) $ as your target labels ? That way you can have your neural network compute $f(y_1, y_2 | x_1, x_2, ..., x_{20})$ which is the quantity you want.

Comment: @Curious  I have no real reason to _not_ go down that road, to be honest. I thought that since each of the features could be any value from within $\mathbb{R}$ and since each of the target values came from a smaller range: it made more sense to arrange the data in the way I did. Thanks for the comment, I will give it a try.